# What is meant by "minimal" key?

Tags: normalization

I'm going though some past papers for my database exam and it asks:

> Specify all minimal keys for R

```
R(A,B,C,D,E)
A → B
CD → E
E → A
B → D
```

I am unsure what is meant by minimal key, I've tried googling it but it only comes up with minimal superkeys. Does it just mean shortest candidate keys: CD, CA, CE, CB?

I'm getting confused as in each question he uses a different name for it and as far as I understand a minimal superkey is a candidate key?

Comment: Yes, in some textbooks, they sometimes use "key" and they mean "superkey". So "minimal key" would be "minimal superkey".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am in the same exam as you, I have asked Paolo what is meant by this: 
Minimal key and candidate key determine all other attributes in a relationship.

a primary key is a candidate key chosen as the smallest number of unique attributes.

He states that a minimal key is the fewest number of attributes so he means a primary key when he says minimal

Comment: Smallest number of attributes is not a correct definition for minimal key. A relation could have `a` and `b,c,d` as candidate keys. They would both be minimal, despite one having 1 and the other 3 attributes.

Comment: But the minimal would be a due to it having the minimal number of attributes would it not? (i may be wrong just trying to understand this topic)

Comment: No, it would not. `b,c.d` would be minimal, too,

Comment: so if we are asked to find all minimal keys we are actually just finding candidate keys?